# Nav bar? Where are you?

Tags: bug, support, status-bydesign, design

Why is the top navigation bar not fixed to the top? When I scroll down, I can't see it.

[image]

But, on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), the navigation bar is fixed to the top and can be seen even after scrolling down.

[image]

Any particular reason why this is not implemented on this site? The fixed navbar is pretty useful (easy to navigate). For example, if you want to change tabs: go to profile, check reputation, check inbox, etc.

Checked it on Google Chrome as well as Firefox.

Comment: I think Stack Overflow often have different design details than the rest of Stack Exchange. I think Code Review has the same navbar behavior as most other sites. Which one is "right" however, that I do not know.

Comment: Untill now, I've only used SO and CR among the Stack Exchange websites. I have about no experience/knowledge about web development, but, usually aren't navbars fixed to the top? I see no disadvantages with it being fixed on this site (a lot of advantages though).

Comment: @KeyurPotdar It depends on the site. Reddit and Imgur don't, as the don't want you to navigate much. Facebook being a social media site however has a sticky nav and much more, as it improves the standard interactions. However, this would be best on Meta.SE, and IIRC they have plans to make things more common between each site. This may be one of the ways.

Comment: Found a cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen-optional

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design, the floating nav bar is only on Stack Overflow, I checked other sites on the Stack Exchange network and they all have the same behavior (nav bar locked on top of page, not floating). In fact, you can set your user preferences on Stack Overflow to also be like that, if you want, so that is the default behavior on the network.

[image]